# How might I convert this SQL code to LINQ?

Tags: sql, linq

How might I convert this SQL code to LINQ?

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1  
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL AS Expr1
            FROM tbl2 AS tbl2_1
            WHERE (T = 'literal') AND tbl1.Id = someId)
```

This is what I have, but it doesn't work:

```
from a in Tbl1 
let b = from b in Tbl2 select b.someId   
let c = from c in Tbl2 select c.T 
where (!c.Contains("literal") & !(b.Contains(a.Id)))
select a
```

Comment: Please expand on "doesn't work".

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick:

```
from t1 in Tbl1
where !(from t2 in Tbl2
    where t2.T == "literal"
    select t2.someId)
       .Contains(t1.Id)
select t1
```

Comment: @user You're welcome. Since my response worked for you, please be sure to accept it as the answer (click the checkmark next to it.)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this:

```
var query =
    from a in Tbl1
    join b in Tbl2 on a.Id equals b.someId into bs
    where !bs
        .Where(b2 => b2.T == "literal")
        .Any()
    select a;
```